# In Godot, what are the GDExtension bindings for the await operator?

Tags: rust, godot

I am trying to write a per-frame loop in Rust using the gdext wrapper crate (https://github.com/godot-rust/gdext) around the GDExtension API.

The gdscript I was toying with before uses `await RenderingServer.frame_post_draw` , but I am struggling to find the way to do this in the GDExtension API or in the gdext crate.

How can GDextension code emulate the `await` operator from gdscript?

Comment: I don't know how to use `await`, or anything of Godot, form rust. - With that said, presumably you can make a connection to the signal (perhaps using `CONNECT_ONE_SHOT`), is that viable to you?